# react navigation own header component

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation

I created a own header file to use this as the header in stack screen.

It shows me the file but it shows the static datas too. Its overide and now I have 2 title and 2 buttons. What do I am wrong?

```
import HeaderAuth from '../shared/headerAuth';
...
...
export function Home() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={TabBar} />
        <Stack.Screen name="addProduct" component={EmptyScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="AuthRegister" component={AuthRegister}
         options={
          ({ navigation }) => ({
            headerStyle: {
              elevation: 0,
              shadowOpacity: 0,
              flexDirection: 'row',
              justifyContent: 'space-between'
            },
            headerLeft: () => <HeaderAuth />,
        })} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

I am very thankful for your help!!

Comment: show an example of what you want